# Unexpected alignment with float:left and float:right in div elements

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing some issues that I do not know how to solve.

This is the result I'm getting: 
[image]

And this is the desired result: (quick wire-framing)
[image]

html code:

```
<div id="fileOutput">
    <h2><center>DASHBOARD</center></h2>
    <div id="tittletextbox1"><img src="images/computer.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Basics</div>
    <div id="textbox1"></div>
    <div id="tittletextbox2"><img src="images/network.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Networking</div>
    <div id="textbox2"></div>
</div>
```

Both text boxes are filled with JavaScript objects.

CSS:

```
div#fileOutput{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}   

div#tittletextbox1{
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
}

div#tittletextbox2{
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
}

div#textbox1{
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}

div#textbox2{
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the divs and remove white-space:pre-line, I think you will have what you are looking for.

```css
div#fileOutput{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}   

div#tittletextbox1{
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
}

div#tittletextbox2{
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
}

div#textbox1{
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}

div#textbox2{
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}
```

```html
<div id="fileOutput">
    <h2><center>DASHBOARD</center></h2>
    <div>
        <div id="tittletextbox1"><img src="images/computer.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Basics</div>
        <div id="tittletextbox2"><img src="images/network.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Networking</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="textbox1"></div>
        <div id="textbox2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the elements from left side into one `div`, and the ones from the right into the other.

This way, your `#textbox1` just stacks to the left of `#tittletextbox1`, causing the latter boxes to collapse below their 80% of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="left-wrapper">
    <div id="tittletextbox1"><img src="images/computer.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Basics</div>
    <div id="textbox1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-wrapper">
    <div id="tittletextbox2"><img src="images/network.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Networking</div>
    <div id="textbox2"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#left-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
}

div#right-wrapper{
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}
```

https://jsbin.com/qiliyageri/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not a good idea to put different values of `float` among sibling elements.
Removing the `white-space` property, reordering divs and adding a `clearfix` div did the trick.

```css
div#fileOutput {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}
div#tittletextbox1 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
div#tittletextbox2 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
div#textbox1 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div#textbox2 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="fileOutput">
  <h2><center>DASHBOARD</center></h2>
  <div id="tittletextbox1">
    <img src="images/computer.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">Basics
  </div>
  <div id="tittletextbox2">
    <img src="images/network.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">Networking
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="textbox1">Text</div>
  <div id="textbox2">Text</div>
</div>
```